# Set-AzDataFactoryV2 : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PublicNetworkAccess'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, endpoint, powershell-az-module

I am trying to disable Public Network Access of Azure Data Factory through az powershell. As per Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2?view=azps-8.0.0), there is a property called PublicNetworkAccess. So I tried below commands,

```
Import-Module Az.DataFactory
Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -PublicNetworkAccess 'Disabled' -Force
```

But it gave me below error,
[image: error]

Could anyone please guide me?
My end goal is to achieve below configuration in Azure Data Factory (Connect via Private Endpoint):
[image: Network Access via ADF Private Endpoint]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `DataFactoryName,ResourceGroupName,location` to the `Set-AzDatatFactoryV2` cmdlet in order to disable the public Network Access on the Data Factory.

We have tested the below PowerShell cmdlet, and we are able to disable the public Network Access on Data Factory.

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName '<resourcegroupName>' -Name '<dataFactoryName>' -Location '<locationOfDataFactory>' -PublicNetworkAccess disabled
```

**Here is the Sample Output screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Module Az.DataFactory
Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -PublicNetworkAccess 'Disabled' -Force
```

The above script which you mentioned is **working fine**. You just need to type the **Resource group name**, **Data factory name** and **location** after executing it like below.

[image]

You can see my `PublicNetworkAccess` is **Disabled** above and below in the Data factory as well.

[image]

My `Az` module version is **8.0.0** and `Az.Accounts` module version is **2.8.0** and `Az.Resources` version is **6.0.0**.

So, may be the issue arise **due to the Az modules version**.

Please check the version of the modules with the command below

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az
```

Try to **upgrade** the `Az` module, `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Resources` modules in the portal and check the versions again and try the `PublicNetworkAccess` after that. It may work.

Please **refer** [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules) to **upgrade the Az modules**.